# Text files no longer updating templates

Tags: templates

I am building a new site using EE 6.06. I got everything set up with fields, channels, templates, partials, etc. and I was able to use my favorite IDE to edit the content, but when I sat down to work today that connection no longer works. When I create new templates they do not show up in the Templates folder on server side and when I make any edits to existing templates on my side and try to upload them, the server does not recognize the changes. Template folder permissions is set to 777.

I checked in phpMyAdmin and new templates appear in the database but they do not show up in the Template files.

Fortunately I can edit in the EE control panel, but the convenience of editing in my IDE is lost.

Any clues what the solution to this dilemma might be? I have been building EE sites for more than ten years and have never seen anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do not have preference set to save templates as files.
Add this to your `config.php`

> $config['save_tmpl_files'] = 'y';

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system-configuration-overrides.html#save_tmpl_files

Comment: Yuri, thank you for the help on this. I reviewed my config.php file and discovered that I had actually duplicated $config['save_tmpl_files'] = 'y'; and the last reference had it set to 'n'. Alas user error :(